# split rows into columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have table similar to this table:

```
     id      val  
0   abc_1    5
1   abc_1    3
2   abc_1    7
3   abc_2    12
4   abc_2    6
5   abc_2    9
...
```

I want to "split" the rows into columns based on the id, so the result should be:

```
     id      val1   val2   val3  
0   abc_1    5       3       7
1   abc_2    12      6       9
```

I was trying to do it by creating groups and then use pivot :

```
df['group'] = (df.index // 3) + 1

>>>
     id      val    group  
0   abc_1    5       1
1   abc_1    3       1
2   abc_1    7       1
3   abc_2    12      2
4   abc_2    6       2
5   abc_2    9       2
```

but then then when I was using pivot I got many new columns al with null values.

**My goal is to get this desired output , open to other solutions as well.**

...

```
     id      val1   val2   val3  
0   abc_1    5       3       7
1   abc_2    12      6       9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
(df.assign(val_names = [f'val{i}' for i in df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1])
 .pivot(index='id', columns='val_names', values='val')
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
 .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
      id  val1  val2  val3
0  abc_1     5     3     7
1  abc_2    12     6     9
```

Comment: error : 
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: try the solution I have just updated.

Comment: that worked but the weird thing is instead of adding only 3 columns it added 10 , some of them are null

Comment: I guess you are using the code I provide with a different dataset from the one of your posted question. Try the following dataframe `text = """
     id      val  
0   abc_1    5
1   abc_1    3
2   abc_1    7
3   abc_2    12
4   abc_2    6
5   abc_2    9
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby + cumcount` to determine which column a value should go into. Then pivot, then reset index and rename columns as demanded:

```
df["col_num"] = df.groupby("id").val.cumcount() + 1

df \
    .pivot(index="id", columns="col_num", values="val") \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1) \
    .rename({col: f"val_{col}" for col in df["col_num"]}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      id  val_1  val_2  val_3
0  abc_1      5      3      7
1  abc_2     12      6      9
```